# Lost audio after installing VLC on 16.04

Tags: 16.04, sound

I have a NUC computer that has only one USB outlet along with the HDMI outlet. So the HDMI goes to my monitor where it has an audio jack that I send my audio to an amplifier and speaker system.

I just loaded in Ubuntu 16.04 yesterday coming from Ubuntu 14.04. Everything was working fine, including my audio, but somehow now I have lost my audio. About the last thing I did was to load VLC in on this new system. Which I have now removed, but still no audio.

So did something happen in Ubuntu to block my audio or is it somewhere in my monitor that converts the HDMI signal to the audio jack?

Answer (score 0):

Go to System Settings/Sound, choose the Output tab. Make sure that **Mute** is not checked, **volume** is set high enough, and make sure that **Play Sound Through** is correctly set to your HDMI output. Also check **Show Sound Volume in the Menu Bar**. Cheers, Al

Comment: Thanks for the response. I had already done all of that. I ended up removing VLC and then rebooted the computer and now the audio is working.